# Select-Xml shows only the child nodes that are in the first node

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, powershell-3.0

The following will display a child element if and only if it's in the first parent element.

```
$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <par><commonchild>Hi there.</commonchild><otherchild>This is displayed.</otherchild></par>
    <par><commonchild>Hi again.</commonchild><otherchild>So is this.</otherchild></par>
    <par><commonchild>Well hello.</commonchild><missingchild>This is missing.</missingchild></par>
    <par><commonchild>Cheers.</commonchild><missingchild>So is this.</missingchild></par>
</root>
"@

cls
Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//par" | select -ExpandProperty node
```

Output

```
commonchild otherchild        
----------- ----------        
Hi there.   This is displayed.
Hi again.   So is this.       
Well hello.                   
Cheers.
```

How can we instead display all the child elements of all parents? For instance, the following works but sometimes we don't know all the child element names.

```
cls
Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//par" | 
    select -ExpandProperty node | 
    select commonchild, otherchild, missingchild
```

Output

```
commonchild otherchild         missingchild    
----------- ----------         ------------    
Hi there.   This is displayed.                 
Hi again.   So is this.                        
Well hello.                    This is missing.
Cheers.                        So is this.
```

Comment: Star is "any" - so probably `//*` ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That doesn't do it.

Comment: It does not do what? `Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//*"` gives you all nodes... you just need to figure out what to do with them because "all" includes `root` as first node which I believe confuses output... try `/root//*` with your original code for somewhat non-empty output

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I tried your suggestion of using `/root//*` with my original code. The output only shoes commonchild and other child; it doesn't show the missing child. In other words, I ran this `Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "/root//*" | select -ExpandProperty node` without any further success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pars = (Select-Xml -XPath "//par" -Content $xml)
$childNodes = ($pars.Node.ChildNodes.Name | select -Unique)
$pars.Node | select $childNodes

commonchild                otherchild                 missingchild             
-----------                ----------                 ------------             
Hi there.                  This is displayed.                                  
Hi again.                  So is this.                                         
Well hello.                                           This is missing.         
Cheers.                                               So is this.
```

So [`XmlNode.ChildNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a hidden property that is only exposed by `Get-Member` if you throw the `-Force` parameter on it. Basically, I'm using that property to get the names of the child nodes and then filtering that so I only have one of each using the `select -Unique` command. I'm then saving those names in a variable called `$childNodes` and using that variable as the value on the `-Property` parameter on the final `select`.

Comment: That's just what I wanted. Thank you. I wonder how it will perform with extremely large (e.g. 50 MB XML files). I.e. it will probably have to read the entire file first before running `select $childnodes`.

Answer (score 3):

Try it using `Format-Table` (ft) to pick out the properties you want displayed:

```
C:\PS> Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '/root//*' | % Node | ft name,'#text'

Name                                                        #text
----                                                        -----
par
commonchild                                                 Hi there.
otherchild                                                  This is displayed.
par
commonchild                                                 Hi again.
otherchild                                                  So is this.
par
commonchild                                                 Well hello.
missingchild                                                This is missing.
par
commonchild                                                 Cheers.
missingchild                                                So is this.
```

`Select -ExpandProperty <name>` is meant to expand properties that are collections - flattening the collection's items into the pipeline.  While it also works (as a side-effect I suppose) to show a particular scalar property's value, as you can see, it doesn't always work well.  :-)

Comment: This does work to pick out the properties that I want to display. Then, I can use a specific projection via `select property1, property2, property3`. @Nacimota's answer is more what I desired because it obviates the need for a specific projection.